# C++ string::find crashes application

Tags: c++, string, find

So I want to check if my `const std::string &foo = "hello world";` contains another string `const std::string &bar = "world";`.

So I tried to use if statement like this: `if (foo.find(bar) != std::string::npos)`. There is no errors but when I start my application it crashes. When I remove that code application works fine again.

Can somebody tell me how to use this function?

I tried to found reason, another tutorial but my code seems to be fine. And yeah I'm sure that I made a mistake somewhere.

EDIT:

Code:

```
#include "modelLoader.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <strstream>
#include <string>

ModelAsset *ModelLoader::loadOBJModel(FilePath *objFile)
{
ModelAsset *model = new ModelAsset();

std::ifstream file(objFile->getPath());

std::vector<std::string*> lines;

std::string tempLine;

while(std::getline(file, tempLine))
{
    lines.push_back(&tempLine);
}

for(U32 i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    if((*lines[i])[0] == '#') continue;
    else if((*lines[i])[0] == 'v' && (*lines[i])[1] == ' ')
    {
        F32 tempX, tempY, tempZ;
        sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "v %f %f %f %f", tempX, tempY, tempZ);

        model->verticles.push_back(new Vector3(tempX, tempY, tempZ));
    }
    else if((*lines[i])[0] == 'v' && (*lines[i])[1] == 'n')
    {
        F32 tempX, tempY, tempZ;
        sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "vn %f %f %f %f", tempX, tempY, tempZ);

        model->normalVectors.push_back(new Vector3(tempX, tempY, tempZ));
    }
    else if((*lines[i])[0] == 'v' && (*lines[i])[1] == 't')
    {
        F32 tempX, tempY, tempZ;
        sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "vt %f %f %f %f", tempX, tempY, tempZ);

        model->textureVectors.push_back(new Vector3(tempX, tempY, tempZ));
    }
    else if((*lines[i])[0] == 'f')
    {
        U16 counter = std::count(lines[i]->begin(), lines[i]->end(), '/');

        if(counter == 0)
        {
            S32 v1, v2, v3;
            sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d %d %d", v1, v2, v3);

            model->faces.push_back(new Face(v1, v2, v3));
        }
        else if(counter == 3)
        {
            S32 v1, v2, v3;
            S32 vt1, vt2, vt3;
            sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", v1, vt1, v2, vt2, v3, vt3);

            model->faces.push_back(new Face(v1, v2, v3, vt1, vt2, vt3));
        }
        else if(counter == 6)
        {

            /* Just testing if find works fine */
            const std::string &main = "hello world";
            const std::string &part = "world";

            if(main.find(part) != std::string::npos)
            {
                S32 v1, v2, v3;
                S32 vn;
                sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", v1, vn, v2, vn, v3, vn);

                model->faces.push_back(new Face(v1, v2, v3, vn));
            }
            else
            {
                S32 v1, v2, v3;
                S32 vn;
                S32 vt1, vt2, vt3;
                sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", v1, vt1, vn, v2, vt2, vn, v3, vt3, vn);

                model->faces.push_back(new Face(v1, v2, v3, vt1, vt2, vt3, vn));
            }
        }
    }
}

    return model;
}
```

When I remove all with if(main.find...) my program works.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Post a short, complete program that shows the problem.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have done. I suspect the error is in the code you *didn't* post.

Comment: @Pete Becker Why does not it compile?

Comment: It compiles with c++11 using compiler on Linux. Without this Code it works fine.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - there are no `#include` directives, so `std::string` isn't known, and the code is not in a function. It also won't link because there is no `main` function.

Comment: When I put these code fragments together in a complete example it runs fine (on VS2015).  Can you post a complete example that demonstrates the crash please?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile with C++11 compiler on Linux or any other compiler. Some other code that you have does, but that doesn't show what the problem is.

Comment: @PeteBecker Are you serious? You were shown a code snippet not a whole program. So you answer does not make any sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - sigh. Exactly. It's a snippet, not a whole program. It doesn't compile, and I, for one, am not willing to guess at what might surround it.

Comment: Thanks for updating with a sample.  There's a lot in here.  Where does it crash?  Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: If we make up the rest of the program ourselves then we won't introduce the bug that the OP had, he needs to post a program that compiles.

Comment: Yeah it crashes when it arrives if statement. if (main.find...)

Comment: I won't post all of my source code because there is around 100 classes that works together and that one depends on many others. Application closes without any errors, just closes like a normal return in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the sscanf lines:

```
S32 v1, v2, v3;
S32 vn;
sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", v1, vn, v2, vn, v3, vn);
```

sscanf expects to be given the address to store the value it has parsed from the string.  These calls here pass the uninitialized values of v1, vn etc. as the address, resulting in sscanf writing the results to random places in memory.

This should get you closer to your goal:

```
sscanf(lines[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", &v1, &vn, &v2, &vn, &v3, &vn);
```

(I notice that '&vn' is passed multiple times here, which may not be what is intended)